# r tm extract doc ids after sort operation

Tags: r, tm

I have mindfreeze around this issue. I am extracting most frequent words from a `tm::dtm`, like so:

```
> s1<-sort(rowSums(as.matrix(dtm10[,])), decreasing=TRUE)
```

I get:

```
290 429 318 125 128 425 431 153  52 385 144 491 126 423 111 130 492 163 176 391 
916 875 860 851 844 823 822 766 759 743 701 700 686 673 670 669 663 658 652 623`
```

But the doc ids and `rowSums` are in a tuple.

```
> s1[2]
429 
875
```

where 429 is doc id and rowsum is 875. I have no further use of the `rowSums`, how do I get a list of the sorted doc ids? I am looking for a vector output like:

```
290 429 318 125 128 425 431 153  52 385 144 491 126 423 111 130 492 163 176 391
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `names(s1)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's it. please post this as an answer, if you want karma points. As an aside, earlier when I needed the stats (rowSums), i would use as.vector(s1). Is there a short cut here?

Comment: added that as an answer with some explanation. Let me know if something is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1` is a named vector with names as 290, 429, 318 etc and values like 916,875, 860 and so on.

To extract only the names of `s1` , we can use,

```
names(s1)
```

which would give :

```
#290 429 318 125 128 425 431 153  52 385 144 491 126 423 111 130 492 163 176 391
```